# Angualrjs ng-if by platform

Tags: angularjs

how can i use angularjs ng-if to evaluate this expression :

`deviceInformation.platform  === 'Win32NT'`

**I try :**

`<div ng-if="deviceInformation.platform  === 'Win32NT'">`

But did not work. I just tried alert() and can see "Win32Nt" as a response.

Comment: You could put a function, or you could manipulate your entities before you output them to the UI

Comment: 'Win32Nt' !== 'Win32NT'. Are you trying to do a case insensitive check?

Comment: No! is Win32NT that was a typo

Comment: i am new to angularJS how do you sugest put a function, or manipulate your entities

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ng-if takes a angular expression as an argument, and as written in the [Developer Guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression):

> In Angular, expressions are evaluated against a scope object.

this means you need to set a scope variable called `deviceInformation` for this to work.

you could do this through a controller:

```
app.controller('someCtrl', ['$scope', '$window', function($scope, $window){
    $scope.deviceInformation = $window.deviceInformation;
}]);
```

Comment: thank you it work´s `<div ng-if="deviceInformation === 'Win32NT'">`. In the controller i have : `$scope.deviceInformation = deviceInformation.platform;`

Comment: grate. that is same as `$window.deviceInformation.platform`

Answer (score 0):

Please check once that "deviceInformation" is `$scope.deviceInformation`  variable or just an javascript variable because it depends on angularjs scope variable which are allowed in ng-if.

Also you can build a function which returns direct

```
$scope.deviceInformationinfo  = function(){
    return  deviceInformation.platform; 
}
```

then you can check it there in ngif

```
<div ng-if="deviceInformationinfo() == 'win32NT'">
```

also check  variable  type please.

Not  Tested

Comment: i was using   `var deviceInformation = ionic.Platform.device();` and then `<div ng-if="deviceInformation.platform  === 'Win32NT'">`